# Hide DataGrid Rows After particular number of rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a datagrid which binds and gives me 12 rows.
I want to hide all the rows after the 7th row.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want hide them, or not render them at all?

Comment: Could you please provide some code samples?

Comment: I just want to hide the rows after particular number of rows which in this case is 7 after the binding the data from data table.

Comment: The best way is to add a CSS class with display:none to the rows you want to hide on the server code

Comment: i have tried hiding it in ItemDataBound event, but it works for particular cells and not the entire row

Comment: Show us the code where you tried hiding it in ItemDataBound event

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
 int index = e.Row.RowIndex;

if(index>7)
{
dataGridView1.Rows(index ).Visible = False
}
   }
```